# Is this possible to like a facebook page via OAuth access token

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-like

I am using Facebook open OAuth, to authenticate the user, post comment, check-in and image upload.

I am working on *asp.net 4.0* (c#).

Now I have to "like"  Facebook pages via the access token that I have already. Because I cannot force the user to put his Facebook credential for each likes on a different machine.

I did many searches on Google but still have not found any way to do the same.

Please tell me if the "like page" is possible via the open OAuth (access token) and if yes how can I get this or what is the way.

Thanks.

Comment: Your title makes no sense, please fix.

Comment: I thing the updated comment is more sounds. please read the main text also. Thanks.